# Calculate $F_*{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}$.

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds, pushforward

Let $F:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be the rotation of angle $\theta$. Find $F_*{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}$.

---

Let $(u,v)\in \mathbb R^2$, $T_{F^{-1}(u,v)}F=F$, so
\begin{align*} 
F_*{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}(u,v)&=(T_{F^{-1}(u,v)}F)  \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right |_{(F^{-1} {(u,v)}}\\& = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta &\cos\theta\end{pmatrix} \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right |_{(F^{-1} {(u,v)}} 
\\&=-\sin(\theta) \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \right |_{(u,v)} +\cos(\theta) \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial v} \right|_{(u,v)}
\end{align*}
Is my answer correct? Any help is appreciated !

Comment: What does $T_{F^{-1}(u,v)}F=F$ mean?

Comment: $d_{F^{-1}(u,v)}F=F$ (because $F$ is linear)

Comment: You've (correctly) calculated the push-forward of $\partial/\partial y = (0, 1)$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  Thanks a lot !